# Laravel datatabel taking too long

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

So ,this is my code for evaluate the result with sum of 0 ,

```
 $clients = Client::with('transactions')->where('trash', 0)->get();
 $data = [];
 foreach($clients as $client_data){
 $type_one=collect($client_data->transactions)->where('type',1)->sum('point');
 $type_two =collect($client_data->transactions)->where('type',2)->sum('point');
 $cal = $type_one - $type_two;
 if($cal != 0){
     $data [] = $customer_data;
     } 
  }
```

how to make it clear and faster loading ??

Answer (score 0):

Try server side data tables ,sometimes it takes time to fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. Load datatable data by ajax
[Datatable Doc](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side)

Answer (score 0):

```
$clients = Client::withSum(['transactions as type_one' => function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('type', 1);
            }], 'point')->withSum(['transactions as type_two' => function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('type', 2);
            }], 'point')
        ->where('trash', 0)
        ->get();
```

You can use relation method using withSum Aggregate method instead of doing it in Foreach.

I personally suggest you to create a mysql view where you get record only after `$cal = $type_one - $type_two;`